# Get reference of custom view by id declared in xml from activity

Tags: android, android-layout, view, reference

I have a custom view that extends ImageView and I use it in an XML layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <com.android.example.MyView
            android:id="@+id/myview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <com.android.example.MyView
            android:id="@+id/myview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in my activity I do the usual: setContentView(R.layout.myLayout) .

Now, I need to get the reference of my class/View "MyView" in order to set a custom listener, but I i'm not able to get it from the id.

```
myview (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myview1);
```

returns null.

I tried to look at similar issues but haven't found any that helped me.

Please, note that if I add the View to the layout programmatically from the Activity everything is working fine, but I would like to be able to find what the issue is here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your mylayout.xml file to the question

Comment: Show us the xml for `R.layout.myLayout`

Comment: Added the layout xml...

Comment: You'll need to show us more code if it isn't working. Show us the Activity where you `setContentView` and where you `findViewbyId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue was a stupid cut and paste mistake where I forgot to add the AttributeSet when calling the super()

having

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}
```

instead of

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for posting this - I'd done exactly the same thing and spent a day trying to figure out why findVIewById was returning null. Wouldn't have figured it out if not for your answer, so easy to overlook that!

Answer (score 1):

It does work.

The layout you're using for `setContentView` must be the same layout you have added your custom view to.

Comment: I edited your answer.  The negative "must not be" could be read as n imperative.

Comment: @Blundell I understand that it should work but for some reason it doesn't. Of course the layout is the one with the custom views...